# Why is Rust saying my variable is unused?

Tags: rust

Here's a [Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=586cfa5883d0ea47b8fc026a0eb8fa35), but:

```rust
fn main() {
    // marking var as mutable
    let mut counter = 0;
    counter += 1;
    counter += 3;
    println!("counter: {}", counter);

    // "shadowing" a variable: this is allocating mem for new var, 
    // and replacing the old one after
    let myvar = 5;
    let myvar = 1000;
    println!("myvar: {}", myvar);
}
```

This gives the warning:

```
warning: unused variable: `myvar`
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
19 |     let myvar = 5;
   |         ^^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_myvar`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted
```

I don't quite understand. I use it later in the `println` macro. Why is it saying it is unused?

Perhaps I don't quite understand shadowing yet: I thought it was effectively allocating space for a new variable, writing the new value there, and then making the symbol `myvar` point to that memory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shadowing a variable makes the previous variable *inaccessible* but it doesn't 'overwrite' it or similar.

So your original definition `let myvar = 5;` still exists, it's just not accessible anymore after your second definition `myvar`. However the original still is being tracked by the compiler, and it rightfully complains that you never use it.

Comment: To clarify what "inaccessible" means, the identifier `myvar` won't refer to the first variable since its been shadowed, but its *value* is still accessible by other means like via references. See [this example on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa1b0de6ab9095386266f9d2624436d1).

Answer (score 10):

> I use it later in the `println` macro.

No you don’t. You are using the *new* variable `myvar` that’s shadowing the *previous* variable of the same name. That’s why the compiler correctly complains.

To fix this, remove the unnecessary `let myvar = 5;` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Because you never use it. They are two different variables but with the same name. If you remove the first declaration where you assign 5, nothing changes.